# FullText search with additional where

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, match, where-clause

I'm having trouble working with the match against functionality of MySQL.
I converted my table and a simple query like:

```
SELECT * FROM 'objectclient_objecten' WHERE MATCH('dh_omschrijving) AGAINST ('these search words');
```

works! But.. i want to add other "where" elements. Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM 'objectclient_objecten' WHERE MATCH('dh_omschrijving) AGAINST ('these search words') AND `dh_status` = 1;
```

But then.. No results. It seems impossible to add something after using match. Is this right? Or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

try that

```
   SELECT * FROM 'objectclient_objecten' WHERE MATCH(dh_omschrijving) AGAINST ('these search words') AND `dh_status` = 1;
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---without quotes here
```

MATCH(here columns without quotes) , you are using column between quote.